Excel file generated in Springboot app which is not opening after downloaded from AWS Ec2
I am using below code in my controller
@GetMapping(value = "/export", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> export(HttpServletResponse httpResponse
    ) {
        try {

            List<MyOutPut> data = mydata();
            List<String> fieldsToInclude = List.of("id", "Name");
            ExportRequest<MyOutPut, ExcelDesignOption> request = new ExportRequest<>(
                    ExportRequest.ExportFormat.EXCELSX, data, fieldsToInclude, MyOutPut.class, "export_data", new ExcelDesignOption()
            );

            System.out.println("Data received now");
            ExportUseCase<MyOutPut, ExcelDesignOption> exportUseCase = new ExportUseCase<>();
            ExportResponse response = exportUseCase.execute(request);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", response.getFileName());
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
//            httpResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            System.out.println("Data received now about to render from vendor");
            // Return the file as a byte array response entity

//            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(response.getInputStream(), httpResponse.getOutputStream());
//            httpResponse.flushBuffer();
            InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(response.getInputStream());

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + "export_data.xlsx")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel")).body(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("search operation failed ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error exporting Excel file", e);
        }
    }

This works locally on my windows machine, but when I deploy this on AWS Ec2, and integrate the API from Angular UI, file gets downloaded but not opening.
this is how in angular integrated exporting file from server
.downloadExcel(this.id).subscribe({
      next: ({ blob, filename }) =>
        this.myService.handleFileDownload(blob, filename),
      error: (err) => console.error('File download failed', err)
    });

return this.http.get(url, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        const filename = contentDisposition
          ? contentDisposition.split('filename=')[1].replace(/"/g, '')
          : 'Registered Vendor List.xlsx';

        return { blob: response.body as Blob, filename };
      })
    );


File structure

Error


Why not store digital assets your app needs in S3?

Ensure :

The content type in the response and client is consistent and change it to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet for .xlsx and  application/vnd.ms-excel for .xls there is a mismatch in java code in the header and content type .
The encoding is correct headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", URLEncoder.encode(response.getFileName(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));


I have update code this way HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); , headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", URLEncoder.encode(response.getFileName(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  , return ResponseEntity.ok()                     .headers(headers)                     .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))

Still same issue.
